High RAM usage for ROS2 nodes
I am working on a ROS2 system that involves several nodes. Some are more complex than the others. Recently, we have encountered "out of memory" issues, and had a look to the memory consumption of the nodes, to investigate some possible optimizations.
It appears that ROS2 nodes, even simple ones, consumes quite a lot of memory w.r.t. what they actually do.
As an example, if we consider the add_two_ints_server node from the tutorial, for just spinning and "offering a service", using the default RMW (FastRTPS), the node consumes ~25MB, for just "doing nothing".
Using the CycloneDDS as RMW, the memory usage drops to ~15MB, but that remains quite high for what the node actually does.
With FastRTPS, the node runs actually 11 threads.
With CycloneDDS, only 5 threads.
That might explain the difference.
with the default RWM (FastRTPS)

with CycloneDDS

With several small nodes in the system, the memory consumption can rapidly increase. That even increases with the node complexity (topic publishers/subscribers, timers, …), and might be an issue for embedded platforms.

How can this be explained?
Is that really necessary?
Is there any way to improve that? i.e. how to reduce the required memory usage of a
(simple) node?

I am running ROS2 Iron on Ubuntu 22.04.
Note that my question is similar to the one reported in Monitoring the RAM usage of ROS2, that remained unanswered… :/
Thanks in advance for your feedbacks.

Maybe you can try rmw_zenoh?
